# Radiation pressure at high temperature

Tags: pressure, thermal-radiation

I am reading a book on the history of the hydrogen bomb. The author describes the Teller-Ulam design and explains that the liquid deuterium charge was compressed by the radiation pressure generated by a vaporized plasma of polyethylene. This would allow the generation of pressures orders of magnitude higher than with high explosives.

Is it possible to quickly estimate this pressure? If I assume a temperature of $T=1,000,000K$ and use $P=\frac{4\sigma}{3c}T^4$ I calculate a pressure of about $2.5$ million bars. Is this realistic? How does it compare with explosives?